# Group result in codeigniter query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have table structure like this

```
id  agent_id ticket_number  booked_date 
1   1   ETS716B0PT10246 27 -Jan-2016    
2   1   ETS611B0PT10247 27-Jan-2016 
3   1   ETS479B0PT10248 27 -Jan-2016    
4   1   ETS414B0PT10291 26 -Jan-2016    
5   1   ETS730B0PT10391 26 -Jan-2016    
6   1   ETS982B0PT10396 26 -Jan-2016    
7   1   ETS515B0PT10397 26 Jan 2016
```

From this i want to display  `ticket_number` for each `booked_date` for a particular `agent_id` 
like this

```
27-Jan-2016 
  ETS716B0PT10246
  ETS730B0PT10391   
26 Jan 2016 
  ETS730B0PT10391
  ETS515B0PT10397
```

But i don't know how to accomplish this task

Here is my basic query

```
$this->db->where('agent_id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('spm_agent_tickets');        
        return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `GROUP BY` clause?

```
$this->db->group_by('booked_date`);
```

Comment: refer to the documtentation: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html